# Nil string with [NSString stringWithFormat:] appears as "(null)"

Tags: iphone, string, nsstring

I have a 'Contact' class with two properties : firstName and lastName.
When I want to display a contact's full name, here is what I do:

```
NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", contact.firstName, contact.lastName];
```

But when the firstName and/or lastName is set to nil, I get a "(null)" in the fullName string. To prevent it, here's what I do:

```
NSString *first = contact.firstName;
if(first == nil)  first = @"";
NSString *last = contact.lastName;
if(last == nil)  last = @"";
NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", first, last];
```

Does someone know a better/more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Assuming you are fine with `firstName<space>` or `<space>lastName`:

```
NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
    contact.firstName ?: @"", contact.lastName ?: @""];
```

(`a ?: b` is a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) which stands for `a ? a : b`, without evaluating `a` twice.)

Comment: Great example and useful link

Comment: You can use this approach without having to compromise on the <space>, just do the following afterwards

fullName = [fullName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Answer (score 7):

`NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", first ? first : @"", last ? last : @""];` is certainly a bit more concise, but it has the same error that your original code has which is that fullName would be "firstName " or " lastName" (note the spaces) if one or the other didn't exist. Thus you're forced to write code like

```
NSMutableString* fullName = [NSMutableString string];
if( contact.firstName ) { [fullName appendString:contact.firstName]; }
if( contact.firstName && contact.lastName ) { [fullName appendString:@" "]; }
if( contact.lastName ) { [fullName appendString:contact.lastName]; }
return fullName;
```

for it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I accompished...

```
NSString *lastName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(personRef, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
cell.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",lastName?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",lastName]:@"",(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(personRef, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. Its not as compact as the others, but its more readable I feel (which is always most important to me).

It also has the benefit of removing trailing whitespaces from the beginning and the end.

```
// Remove any nulls from the first or last name
firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (firstName ? firstName : @"")];
lastName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (lastName ? lastName : @"")];

// Concat the strings
fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

// Remove any trailing whitespace
fullName = NSString *newString = [oldString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```